# How to create a flat UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

Today's trend in apps includes flat designs, and now I am doing an app that follows with this trend. My problem now is how to create a UIAcionSheet that match with my App Screen's flat UI Design. In relation with this, I saw Instagram's action sheet and I found it interesting. I wish to have that design in my app. Anyone knows how to implement this in ios apps? I have provided a screen shot from instagram app.[image]

Comment: Create your custom Action-sheet

Comment: I have tried customizing a view to be an actionsheet but as much as possible I want to use a real actionsheet, not a customized one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use RDActionSheet from git

https://github.com/reddavis/RDActionSheet

I hope it will help you..!!

Comment: Thanks, it helped me, I just changed the background images of the button to be like what I attached on my question.

Answer (score 3):

yes,

you can use https://github.com/reddavis/RDActionSheet and also u can change image and color of text and background image of action sheet

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FlatUIKIT` from Git

https://github.com/Grouper/FlatUIKit

Go through the documentation & you will know how to use it. Awesome collection of Flat UI classes.

Comment: thanks for this, I will try and send a feedback later if it works for me or not.

Comment: After studying this UIKit, I found out that I can't use this since it is trying to use the ApplicationServices framework that is not supported by iOS. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass CustomActionSheet derived UIActionSheet,

and create a method called CustomUI in it. Design your code here.

use CustomActionSheet like UIActionSheet, except must call method CustomUI of subclass in willPresentActionSheet delegate:

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
    if ([actionSheet isKindOfClass:[CustomActionSheet class]]) {
    CustomActionSheet *sheet = (CustomActionSheet*)actionSheet;
    [sheet CustomUI];
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, I will try and send a feedback later if it works for me or not.

Comment: As outlined in the UIActionSheet reference in iOS dev library:

UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:.

So I'd avoid doing that.